# How do I include scripting (classic ASP pages, vbscript, etc.) to TcpListener and Socket Web Server Console Application?

Tags: sockets, asp-classic, webserver, tcplistener

Forgive me, as I am new to this.  I found some code online that I'm using in a console application that can set up a local web server, and serve HTML pages locally.  I will post the code - but I need to be able to serve ASP pages and pages with vbscripting.  Is it possible with this code below, and if so, what can I add to do so?  Since this code is so simple, I'm really hoping to modify it to add ASP/Vbscript, and continue on.  Thanks in advance!!

```
Public ip As String = "127.0.0.1"
Public port As String = "80"
Public rootpath As String = "C:\wwwroot\"
Public defaultpage As String = "default.asp"

Public Sub Main()

    Try

        Dim hostName As String = Dns.GetHostName()
        Dim serverIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip)
        Dim tcpListener As New TcpListener(serverIP, Int32.Parse(port))

        tcpListener.Start()

        Console.WriteLine("Web server started at: " & serverIP.ToString() & ":" & Port)

        Dim httpSession As New HTTPSession(tcpListener)

        Dim serverThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf httpSession.ProcessThread))

        serverThread.Start()

    Catch ex As Exception

        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())

    End Try

End Sub

Public Class HTTPSession

    Private tcpListener As System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener
    Private clientSocket As System.Net.Sockets.Socket

    Public Sub New(ByVal tcpListener As System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener)
        Me.tcpListener = tcpListener
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProcessThread()

        While (True)

            Try

                clientSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()

                ' Socket Information
                Dim clientInfo As IPEndPoint = CType(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint)

                Console.WriteLine("Client: " + clientInfo.Address.ToString() + ":" + clientInfo.Port.ToString())

                ' Set Thread for each Web Browser Connection
                Dim clientThread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ProcessRequest))

                clientThread.Start()

            Catch ex As Exception

                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())

                If clientSocket.Connected Then
                    clientSocket.Close()
                End If

            End Try

        End While

    End Sub

    Protected Sub ProcessRequest()

        Dim recvBytes(1024) As Byte
        Dim htmlReq As String = Nothing
        Dim bytes As Int32

        Try
            ' Receive HTTP Request from Web Browser
            bytes = clientSocket.Receive(recvBytes, 0, clientSocket.Available, SocketFlags.None)
            htmlReq = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes, 0, bytes)

            Console.WriteLine("HTTP Request: ")
            Console.WriteLine(htmlReq)

            Dim strArray() As String
            Dim strRequest As String

            strArray = htmlReq.Trim.Split(" ")

            ' Determine the HTTP method (GET only)
            If strArray(0).Trim().ToUpper.Equals("GET") Then
                strRequest = strArray(1).Trim

                If (strRequest.StartsWith("/")) Then
                    strRequest = strRequest.Substring(1)
                End If

                If (strRequest.EndsWith("/") Or strRequest.Equals("")) Then
                    strRequest = strRequest & defaultPage
                End If

                strRequest = rootPath & strRequest

                sendHTMLResponse(strRequest)

            Else ' Not HTTP GET method
                strRequest = rootPath & "Error\" & "400.html"

                sendHTMLResponse(strRequest)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())

            If clientSocket.Connected Then
                clientSocket.Close()
            End If

        End Try

    End Sub

    ' Send HTTP Response
    Private Sub sendHTMLResponse(ByVal httpRequest As String)

        Try

            ' Get the file content of HTTP Request 
            Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpRequest)
            Dim strBuff As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            streamReader.Close()
            streamReader = Nothing

            ' The content Length of HTTP Request
            Dim respByte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strBuff)
            'Dim respByte() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuff)

            ' Set HTML Header
            Dim htmlHeader As String = _
                "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
                "Server: WebServer 1.0" & ControlChars.CrLf & _
                "Content-Length: " & respByte.Length & ControlChars.CrLf & _
                "Content-Type: " & getContentType(httpRequest) & _
                ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf

            ' The content Length of HTML Header
            'Dim headerByte() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(htmlHeader)
            Dim headerByte() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlHeader)

            Console.WriteLine("HTML Header: " & ControlChars.CrLf & htmlHeader)

            ' Send HTML Header back to Web Browser
            clientSocket.Send(headerByte, 0, headerByte.Length, SocketFlags.None)

            ' Send HTML Content back to Web Browser
            clientSocket.Send(respByte, 0, respByte.Length, SocketFlags.None)

            ' Close HTTP Socket connection
            clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
            clientSocket.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString())

            If clientSocket.Connected Then
                clientSocket.Close()
            End If

        End Try

    End Sub

    ' Get Content Type
    Private Function getContentType(ByVal httpRequest As String) As String

        If (httpRequest.EndsWith("html")) Then
            Return "text/html"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("asp")) Then
            Return "text/html"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("htm")) Then
            Return "text/html"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("txt")) Then
            Return "text/plain"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("gif")) Then
            Return "image/gif"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("jpg")) Then
            Return "image/jpeg"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("jpeg")) Then
            Return "image/jpeg"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("pdf")) Then
            Return "application/pdf"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("pdf")) Then
            Return "application/pdf"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("doc")) Then
            Return "application/msword"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("xls")) Then
            Return "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        ElseIf (httpRequest.EndsWith("ppt")) Then
            Return "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
        Else
            Return "text/plain"
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices.

Stop doing that because its certain to be world of pain and cost.

However if you are determined to try and make it happen then take a look at the [ASP Classic Compiler](http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/) codeplex project.

Comment: Well, we don't really have a choice at this point in time, so not doing it is not an option.  I just didn't know if there was an easy way to include scripting in this option - can you explain why it is certain to be a world of pain and cost?